# Javascript with multiple textboxes and progressbars

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a javascript to fill my progressbar with looking to different strings in my textbox. I can get it to work for one progressbar, but if i add a second one they will not work.

Here is my code for when i use only one progressbar.

```
 <script>
        function move1() {
            var textarea1 = document.getElementById('TbProd1');

            var word1 = "Vrijgegeven";
            var word2 = "Gepicked";
            var word3 = "Voltooid";

            var textValue = textarea1.value;
            var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");

            if (textValue == (word1)) {

                var width = 10;
                var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
                function frame() {
                    if (width >= 25) {
                        clearInterval(id);
                    } else {
                        width++;
                        elem.style.width = width + '%';
                        document.getElementById("LblProgBar1").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (textValue == (word2)){
                var width = 25;
                var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
                function frame() {
                    if (width >= 50) {
                        clearInterval(id);
                    } else {
                        width++;
                        elem.style.width = width + '%';
                        document.getElementById("LblProgBar1").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (textValue == (word3)) {
                var width = 50;
                var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
                function frame() {
                    if (width >= 100) {
                        clearInterval(id);
                    } else {
                        width++;
                        elem.style.width = width + '%';
                        document.getElementById("LblProgBar1").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                    }
                }
            }
}
</script>
```

and here is my reusable script for multiple progressbars:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        load('TbProd1', 'myBar', 'LblProgBar1');
        load('TbProd2', 'myBar2', 'LblProgBar2');
    }

    function load(TextboxID, BarID, LblBarID) {
            var textarea1 = document.getElementById(TextboxID);

            var word1 = "Vrijgegeven";
            var word2 = "Gepicked";
            var word3 = "Voltooid";

            var textValue = textarea1.value;
            var elem = document.getElementById(BarID);

            if (textValue == (word1)) {

                var width = 10;
                var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
                function frame() {
                    if (width >= 25) {
                        clearInterval(id);
                    } else {
                        width++;
                        elem.style.width = width + '%';
                        document.getElementById(LblBarID).innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (textValue == (word2)){
                var width = 25;
                var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
                function frame() {
                    if (width >= 50) {
                        clearInterval(id);
                    } else {
                        width++;
                        elem.style.width = width + '%';
                        document.getElementById(LblBarID).innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (textValue == (word3)) {
                var width = 50;
                var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
                function frame() {
                    if (width >= 100) {
                        clearInterval(id);
                    } else {
                        width++;
                        elem.style.width = width + '%';
                        document.getElementById(LblBarID).innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                    }
                }
            }
}
</script>
```

Where is the mistake in my reusable code? It has something to do with window.move1 i think but dot know what.

Edit1: It seems that it cant read the values of my textboxes, how do i make the link with my reusable code?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put your 'frame' function in a local variable instead of just declaring it with the function keyword.  Just declaring a function like that create conflicts in JS engine and the scope of variables become really hard (see impossible) to manage.

Something like

```
 var id = null,
 frameFunction = function() {
    if (width >= 25) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + '%';
        document.getElementById(LblBarID).innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
 }
 id = setInterval(frameFunction , 10);
```

Also window.onload event MIGHT trigger before DOM is ready for manipulation.  This will result in your code being unable to access dom objects and attributes.

You can solve this many ways.

1. Use jquery $(document).ready();
2. Use a stripped down library just for DomReady (https://code.google.com/archive/p/domready/)
3. Use plain ECMA implementation (should work in all modern browsers)

ex.

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      // code...
    });
```

You can see a working example of the latest here
https://jsfiddle.net/zjhyqrff/1/

Comment: Tanks for the tip, i will change my code. But i still have the problem that the script can not read the values from my textboxes when i use the secodn code. Do you know where the problem is?

Comment: This does work on a jsFiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/zjhyqrff/1/   Althought window.onload event might fire before DOM is ready for manipulation.  I will update the answer